# How to split json array and map with the common data in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I want to split Json array which is returning form db and map with the common data which is associated with the main JSON data.
Here is my data from db

```
"users": [
        {
            "_id": "5b56d462c53eb904fcb5a8fc",
            "companyName": "ABC,
            "departmentName": R & D,
            "userName": "Jhon",
            "logs": [
                {
                    "date": "2017-08-29T08:22:00.000Z",
                    "state": "start"
                },
                {
                    "date": "2017-08-29T10:37:18.590Z",
                    "state": "pause"
                },
                {
                    "date": "2017-08-29T10:31:18.590Z",
                    "state": "resume"
                },
                {
                    "date": "2017-08-29T11:51:18.590Z",
                    "state": "stop"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "_id": "5b56d48cc53eb904fcb5a8fd",
            "companyName": "ABC,
            "departmentName": QA,
            "userName": "Doe",
            "logs": [
                {
                    "date": "2017-08-29T08:22:00.000Z",
                    "state": "start"
                },
                {
                    "date": "2017-08-29T10:34:18.590Z",
                    "state": "pause"
                },
                {
                    "date": "2017-08-29T10:39:18.590Z",
                    "state": "resume"
                },
                {
                    "date": "2017-08-29T11:54:18.590Z",
                    "state": "stop"
                },
                {
                    "date": "2017-08-29T13:39:18.590Z",
                    "state": "resume"
                },
                {
                    "date": "2017-08-29T18:54:18.590Z",
                    "state": "stop"
                }
            ]
        },
    ]
```

I want to separate the log data and map them with the details like company name, department name and user name , i have more than 1000 data present in database and my expected result should be like this

```
{
   "companyName": "ABC,
            "departmentName": R & D,
            "userName": "Jhon",
                {
                    "date": "2017-08-29T08:22:00.000Z",
                    "state": "start"
                }
}
{
   "companyName": "ABC,
            "departmentName": R & D,
            "userName": "Jhon",
                {
                    "date": "2017-08-29T10:37:18.590Z",
                    "state": "pause"
                }
},
{
   "companyName": "ABC,
            "departmentName": R & D,
            "userName": "Jhon",
                {
                    "date": "2017-08-29T10:31:18.590Z",
                    "state": "resume"
                }
},
{
   "companyName": "ABC,
            "departmentName": R & D,
            "userName": "Jhon",
                {
                    "date": "2017-08-29T11:51:18.590Z",
                    "state": "stop"
                }
}
```

for all the user details present in db.

Comment: the expected output is wrong

Comment: @brk ok i will agree with but i just want to separate  the log data and mapping them with the  common details. so how can i achieve ?

Comment: @Manasa I can only help if you show me the proper expected output

Comment: Your output is not valid object.

Answer (score 1):

i tries this

```
var array = [];
    var total = users.length;
    users.forEach(function(t) {
        t.logs.forEach(function(log) {
            var data = {"_id":t._id,"userName": t.userName,"departmentName": t.departmentName,"companyName": t.companyName, "date": log.date,"state": log.state};
            time_array.push(content);
        })
    });
```

thanks you all :)